# How to share video when video is downloaded and store in core data

Tags: swift

I want to share downloaded video through activity indication and i am doing this -:

```
 let historyItem = historyArray[value]
    let urlString = historyItem.value(forKey: kConstant.keyName.urlString) as? String

            let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlString!)], applicationActivities: nil)
            activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [.addToReadingList, .assignToContact]
            self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In urlString we have "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1565.MP4" string.
but nothing happens.It gives error Cannot Load Representation Of Type Public.Mpeg-4.

Comment: You have to fetch data from core data and create an url to share.

Comment: i already did this is the line "let urlString = historyItem.value(forKey: kConstant.keyName.urlString) as? String"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, coredata is not suitable for storing data such as videos, photos and files.

I suggest you to store the downloaded video in device memory using FileManager.
First determine where you want to download the downloaded video.

```
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)

    return paths[0]
    }
```

Details on that are available here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/writing-data-to-the-documents-directory

You can see information such as where you should store the video according to the purpose of storage, from the link below.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Use the path from `getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("filename.mp4")` in your download topic.

After determining the location where you will download the video, start the download process.

What I want to emphasize here is that after downloading the video directly to the location you want, we will have the location of this video. Whether you save this location to Core Data or elsewhere is up to you.

To share this video:

```
 let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: paths, applicationActivities: nil)
 if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
    activity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activity.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.height, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
  }
            
 self.getTopMostViewController()?.present(activity, animated: true)
```

Details on that are available here:
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/118/uiactivityviewcontroller-by-example

Remove the line below if you want. It is for iPads.

> if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad { }

If there is any missing or incorrect information, please warn me, I will correct it.